# Oracle ADF declarativeComponent background

Tags: jakarta-ee, oracle-adf

I have a page which consists of two parts: upper one is  and another one is . 
I'v encountered following touble:
how can i apply standart blue-gray backgound (like a af:decorativeBox has) to region with declarativeComponent?
Thanks in advance!

**Edit:**

Here is example of markup:

```
<af:declarativeComponent id=".." .... />
<af:panelTabbed id="..." ...>
    <af:showDetailItem ... />
    ....
 </af:panelTabbed>
```

where declarativeComponent contains simple panelStrecthLayout with various outputLabels, outputTexts, etc.

panelTabbed by default have blue-gray colored backgroud pane but af:decalarativeComponent does not. So how can i apply same backgroud to content of declarativeComponent without modifying content of page which delcarativeComponent references (e.g. wrapping  into decorativeBox will give expected result, but declarativeComponent is not valid child for decorativeBox)

Answer (score 0):

you question is not clear if you want to apply the background in lower or the upper part of the page. Plus it depends on the type of component you are using. If its a panel group layout then you should see the background-color property in the inline style. Further, I think you can apply an image as well which may have changing gradient as a background for a panelGroupLayout

Comment: take a look at question clarification, please.